# Sorting data table after update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, datatable

I am working with a dataTable bound to a gridView on my page. The user can delete and modify gridView rows so that each row is sorted after each change. The dataTable behind the gridView is sorted in ascending order for two fields. One that counts each element in a group and another one that sort groups indexes.

The user can delete groups but the order of the numbers then it is messed up. what I need is to re-index the table each time a group get deleted so that I have sequential numbers with no gaps:

for example:

```
group id    group id sorted
0           0
0           0 
0           0
1           1
1           1
3           2
3           2
6           3
6           3
```

I tried this function but wiht no results (I expected that). Maybe someone has already solved this problem before and can help.

```
 protected void reindexGroupsLayers(DataTable dtLayers)
{
    //after every change to the index structure 
    //this function re-sorts the index
    DataView uniqueGroupIndexesView = new DataView(dtLayers);
    uniqueGroupIndexesView.Sort = "groupindex asc";
    DataTable uniqueGroupIndexesTable = uniqueGroupIndexesView.ToTable(true, "groupindex");
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow uniqueRow in uniqueGroupIndexesTable.Rows)
    {
        int oldIndex = (int)uniqueRow["groupindex"];
        foreach (DataRow groupRow in dtLayers.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)groupRow["groupindex"] == oldIndex)
            {
                groupRow["groupindex"] = i;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    DataView dtLayersView = dtLayers.DefaultView;
    dtLayersView.Sort = "groupindex, layerindex asc";
    DataTable dtLayersSorted = dtLayersView.ToTable();
    gvMapLayers.DataSource = dtLayersSorted;
    gvMapLayers.DataBind();
    Session["webmaplayers"] = dtLayersSorted;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "DataTable" javascript functionality for this problem. Please refer https://www.datatables.net/.

It will set your sorting issue with seting parameter in javascript.

Let me know if you need further help.

Thanks